# Merge two data sets with different amount of years

Tags: vba, merge

I have Problems to find a way to merge two Excel data sets, according to their Project-ID with VBA.

The difficulty is that the "Dataset 1" has all the Project-IDs just once, but the "Dataset" 2 has them for several years. The rest of the dataset differs in the information they present.

"Dataset 1" is structured like this:

Proj.-ID - Project name

473892 - "Name 1"

578393 - "Name 2"

"Dataset 2" is structured like this:

Proj.-ID - Year

578393 - 2017

578393 - 2016

473892 - 2017

473892 - 2018

In the end, I want to create a Pivot-Table out of the merged date. In this Pivot, I want to have Project-ID just once, Project Name and for the Index 1 to 3, seperated by years in columns. Even if this might be not so important for the merge of the data, I wanted to give you a Little bit more insights. 
Hopefully, you have some advices or even solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What has mysql to do with it?

Comment: During my research for this problem, I found that it is used for merging data with different structure.

Comment: Forget mysql (and any other sql) you would have to upload to sql, merge and download to excel to pivot. If all you have at your disposal is excel then write a vba script to merge the 2 worksheets and pivot (nb:- be careful that all users an execute macros/vba - if not you have another problem) - this question belongs in the excel forum in my view.

Comment: Create new dataset 3 with vlookups by mapping proj id to year.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem for the Power Pivot Add-in of Excel.

With Power Pivot you can put your two Dataset together and create a Pivot Table out of it.

Power Pivot is already installed in Excel 2016 for previous Excel versions (2010 & 2013) you can download the Add-in from [support.office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/start-the-power-pivot-add-in-for-excel-a891a66d-36e3-43fc-81e8-fc4798f39ea8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to make sure that it works on different Excel Versions, and cannot say for sure that the Add-in is installed everywhere.

Do you have further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create new dataset 3 with vlookups by mapping proj id to year.
also you can write the VBA script for populate the data to Pivot